# androidx fragment type doesn't match

Tags: android

I'm about to add new features to an Android App but before that Android Studio upgraded Gradle and that created a lot of errors, in the code and in the layout(xml).

I managed to solve most of them but now I have this one:

[image: android Fragment type error]

Also I have another error, *Cannot resolve method getSupportActionBar() in Main Activity*

```
ActionBar mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();//<-- The right part is on red.
```

Full OnCreate() code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ActionBar mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        LayoutInflater mInflater;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);

        View mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_actionbar, null);

        mActionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView);
        mActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);

        homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
        configFragment = new ConfigFragment();
       // inboxFragment = new InboxFragment();

        BottomNavigationView navigation = findViewById(R.id.navigation);

        if(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("SECTION_FRAGMENT") == null)
        {
            String menuSelected = getIntent().getStringExtra("navigation");
            if(menuSelected != null && menuSelected.equals("inbox"))
            {
                navigation.getMenu().getItem(1).setChecked(true);
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.sections_container, inboxFragment, "SECTION_FRAGMENT").commit();
            }
            else
            {
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.sections_container, homeFragment, "SECTION_FRAGMENT").commit();
            }
        }

        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
    }
```

This code was working in a previous version, I don't understand what changed on new libraries.

Answer (score 0):

For the Fragment error, replace `import android.app.Fragment` with `import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment`.

For the `getSupportActionBar()` error, you should extend your MainActivity with `AppCompatActivity` instead of `FragmentActivity`. `FragmentActivity` doesn't have `getSupportActionBar()` method.

Comment: The import solve the type error on the Fragmen but create  new error *Cannot resolve method getSupportFragmentManager()*. Then if I change FragmentActivity by AppCompatActivity 17 new errors appear, first one @Override *Method does not override method from superclass.* Also super.Oncreate, SetContentView, findViewByID, getIntent(). onDestroy() and startActivity  are on red *Cannot resolve method*.

Comment: `AppCompatActivity` inherits from `FragmentActivity` so all the methods is available. `getSupportFragmentManager()` is defined in `FragmentActivity` but also available in `AppCompatActivity` since it inheirts and all the other methods are also available. Can you sync the gradle and check? Also check if the `appcompat` dependency is set in app's `build.gradle`

Comment: I just noticed you already extended from `AppCompatActivity` and commented it out in the screenshot, why is that? why did you use `FragmentActivity` and not `AppCompatActivity`?

Comment: Originally was in AppCompatActivity but got errors and was "solved" by changing to FragmentActivity that created different errors but was like 5 errors against 3. Currently I solved all the errors on the code and is in AppCompatActivity but got a new error when try to run *Can't determine type for tag '<macro name="m3_comp_assist_chip_container_shape">?attr/shapeAppearanceCornerSmall</macro>'*